# Magento 2.3 : Mixin function is not rendering

Tags: magento2.3, mixins

I have a mixin which is extending functionality for validation purpose. See the code below

```
define([
'jquery',
'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator'
], function ($, validatorlib) {
"use strict";
console.log('test');
return function () {
    console.log('test123');  // this is coming in console
    var regex_pattern = window.address_field_pattern;

    if (regex_pattern == '')
        return true;

    validatorlib.addRule(
        'validate-gearalphanumeric',
        function (value) {
            if (value)
                return regex_pattern.test(value);
            else
                return true;

        },
        $.mage.__('Please use only numbers and Latin characters in this field.')
    );

    $.validator.addMethod(
        'validate-gearalphanumeric',
        function (value) {
            if (value)
                return regex_pattern.test(value);
            else
                return true;

        },
        $.mage.__('Please use only numbers and Latin characters in this field.')
    );
}
});
```

> NOTE : It was working in 2.2 version

and I do have verified the implementation as well but it seems not working.

Anyone find any issue in above do let me know.

Comment: did you get any error Prathap?

Comment: No error just it is not coming inside the function which I've given in comment. See code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding validation like this and works for me:

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui',
        'jquery/validate',
        'mage/translate'
    ], function($){
        'use strict';
        $.validator.addMethod(
            "ruleValidationName",
            function(value, element) {
                return false;
            },
            $.mage.__("Your validation message")
        );
    });
```

so no `return function()` is needed

Comment: Please update complete implementation. So I could try that

Comment: I've removed the return function then it worked but what does the difference here..

Comment: you are not returning a function since you don;t need to make a mixin for validations, you can just add them in a custom script, that is why you dont need that part